# Can't access service running in docker

Tags: docker, localhost, docker-for-mac

I'm unable to access a nodejs based service via `http://localhost:8000` running in a docker image. I'm using Docker for Mac (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/)

I'm following the tutorial here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/.

The server runs on port 8000. I start the docker image with the following:

```
$ docker run -p 8000:8000 -d geuis/node-server:latest
```

If I run `docker ps` I see:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
9fa2e446918b        geuis/node-server:latest   "npm start"         6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   unruffled_lewin
```

If I `docker exec -it 9fa2e446918b /bin/bash` I can access the docker vm and I can `curl http://localhost:8000` and access the server from inside the container.

However, I try the same `curl http://localhost:8000` from my system terminal and its not accessible.

Not sure what I need to do next.

Comment: I tried it with docker for mac and it works. Do you have any other modification besides the port?

Comment: Can you access the service with the default Docker IP, .i.e http://192.168.99.100:8000? (or any other IP if you have specified one other than the default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following listen statement:

```
app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0');
```

From reading the tutorial you mention it looks like express is listening on `localhost`. This is fine if you're running locally but inside of a container, `localhost` is not the same `localhost` that's outside of the container.

`0.0.0.0` is the [unspecified IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) and so Express will bind on any IP it can find, which will be the IP that your requests are coming in from outside the container.

Comment: Yep this was it. Using hapijs instead of Express, but same solution.